# ctrl+delete with multiple rows in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

When selecting multiple rows in Notepad++ the short cut 'ctrl + delete' only works for the last row. Does anyone know how to make it work for all rows?

Comment: The default installation of Notepad++ (with no plugins installed) does not map Ctrl+Del to anything. What plugin do you use that configures it, and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: According to http://www.keyxl.com/aaacd5a/43/Notepad-Plus-text-editor-software-keyboard-shortcuts.htm - Ctrl+Del will erase all white spaces until the next character. I like this functionality for sql formatting.

Comment: I don't have that key combination on the Windows install (v5.9.6.2 Unicode), according to the ShortCut Mappings dialog. It also has no functionality when editing a file. ?? Actually, according to the URL you posted, "Ctrl-Delete - Delete to end of word", which doesn't work in my install.

Comment: I'm using 5.9.3. add a couple of white spaces at the beginning of a line and then have a letter. Move the cursor to first column and hit Ctrl+Del. The white spaces should disappear and that letter be at the beginning of the row. Does that work for you?

Comment: Yep, it does. It seems that's part of the Scintilla key mappings (`Settings->Shortcut mapper`, `Scintilla commands` tab, `SCI_DELWORDRIGHT` (item #87)). It doesn't register anywhere on a menu item or elsewhere in the shortcut mappings AFAICT.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Thanks! So, is there a way to make work with several selected rows?

Comment: You can use the `Edit->Blank Operations->Trim Leading Space`. You can probably use the shortcut mappings to make a shortcut to that operation. Yep, `Shortcut Mappings->Main Menu`, item #28; just assign that a keystroke combination you'd like to use.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl+Del</kbd> doesn't appear to work with multiple lines selected.

You can use the menu item `Edit->Blank Operations->Trim Leading Spaces`, and create your own keyboard shortcut via `Settings->Shortcut Mapper`, `Main Menu` tab, item #28.